# Repetir estadistica Chart.js con un foreach

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Buenas tardes estoy trabajando en una web y me surgió la necesidad de crear algunas estadísticas visuales y comencé a usar chart. El problema que me surge es que necesito que se muestren varias estadísticas del mismo tipo una vez se carguen datos, por ende estoy utilizando un simple foreach para recorrer los datos, pero solo se muestran una sola vez y con los últimos datos cargados.

```
<?php foreach ($datos as $d){
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
          <canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
          var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
              datasets: [{
                data:[
                  <?php foreach ($estadistica1 as $s){
                    echo $s['p'];?>,<?php echo $s['s'];?>,<?php echo $s['f'];}?>],

                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(15,255,0)",
                  "rgba(255,243,0)",
                  "rgba(255,0,0)",
                ],
                label: 'Dataset 1'
              }],
              labels: ['dato1', 'dato2', 'dato3'],
            },
            options: {
            }
          };

          window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
            window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
          };

          var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);
          document.getElementById('addDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var newDataset = {
              backgroundColor: [],
              data: [],
              label: 'New dataset ' + config.data.datasets.length,
            };

            config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
            window.myPie.update();
          });

        </script>
}?>
```

Mi primera impresion es por el id que contiene al llamar al javascript, pero quiero saber si existe solución.

Comment: Tambien creo que es por el id.  Necesitas usar clases en lugar de id.

Comment: Si, el problema es que ese id viene incluido en el código de la librería, yo supongo que debe existir una forma de que se pueda agregar más de una estadistica.